# HTML content is going out of frame in Flask Template

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am creating a Flask Music App
And this is how the base layout looks like
[image]

This is the code for the file ````layout.html```

```
<body> 
    <header>
        <div class="banner-text">
            <a href="/" class=logo>SPOTS</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li href='about.html'>About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="animation-area">
        <ul class="box-area">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

and this is the file `home.html`

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <h2>Come, Let's Create a Playlist</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Let's Go</button>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I want the content, with the text 'Come, Let's Create a Playlist' and the button to be in the centre

but the home.html file looks like this
[image]

Edit: style.css file

```
.content-section h2{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.animation-area {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #8942a8, #ba382f);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.box-area {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How should I get it inside the frame?

Comment: Where is the CSS ? Post it as well.

Comment: @Ram The CSS file is quite huge. I have added just the content-section css block here

Comment: You don't need to post the entire file here. Just post what is relevant to this question.

Comment: @Ram, please have a look now

Answer (score 0):

You should style the `content-section` `<div>` like this:

```
.content-section {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is how it looks like:

```css
.content-section {
    text-align: center;
}

.animation-area {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #8942a8, #ba382f);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.box-area {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-section h2{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

</head>
<body> 
    <header>
        <div class="banner-text">
            <a href="/" class=logo>SPOTS</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li href='about.html'>About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="animation-area">
        <ul class="box-area">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   <div class="content-section">
        <h2>Come, Let's Create a Playlist</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Let's Go</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem lies in the ```layout.html``` file in the part where I have added ```{% block content %}{% endblock %}```, because the changes you mentioned in the solution still places the content out of the frame.

Comment: You have to check other CSS rules then. I have also added a code snippet to my answer. You may check it out.